How to Clear "Private files "Not fully protected" error in status report
I am trying to get rid of the Private files "Not fully protected" error in the Drupal 10 status report.
Added $settings['file_private_path'] = $app_root . '/../private'; to settings.php.
Created a folder named "private" at the same level as web folder.
Set folder owner to www-data
Tried everything recommend at the Drupal issues page about this at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2953336.
The error still shows in the status report.  I am not allowing users to upload files, I just want the error to go away.

permission must be "private" directory has permissions set to 750 or 770
and is owned by the web server user
(www-data for apache) use the next
sudo chmod -R 750 /path/to/private
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/private

clear the cache after that using drush cr

For clarities sake, here are all the steps I took to remove the error in the Status report. Note the "private" folder may be at a different location, but I did not try that.

Create a folder named "private at the same level as "web"
sudo chmod -R 750 /path/to/private
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/private
Added $settings['file_private_path'] = $app_root . '/../private'; to settings.php.
Modified and saved any setting in Configuration->Media->File System.
Cleared all caches.

I had done all of the above except used a different permission for the private folder.
sudo chmod -R 750 /path/to/private   Was the key to having the error go away!
